# CSS3 property column-count. Different display in Chrome, Firefox and Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

Please see this [code example](http://jsfiddle.net/rjkb4291/) in different browsers. In firefox, safari we always see 8 columns with text. But in Chrome last columns are empty. How is this CSS property supposed to work? Or how to make it look like Chrome in Safari?

```
<div style="text-align: justify; border: solid; -webkit-columns: 8; -moz-column-count: 8; font-size: 12px; line-height: 2; height: 500px;">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ornare, nunc eget condimentum tempor,
augue ligula accumsan eros, sed consequat sapien orci id libero. Curabitur tristique, augue in aliquet
accumsan, nibh nisi lobortis odio, et suscipit est ligula eu nisi. Nunc aliquet lobortis porta. Donec
venenatis consectetur eleifend. Etiam sed tempor quam. Pellentesque gravida gravida eros venenatis
suscipit. Aenean diam enim, suscipit id pellentesque vel, hendrerit et metus. Suspendisse felis erat,
hendrerit a congue in, euismod ac erat. Donec pulvinar venenatis tortor, a lobortis erat scelerisque
et. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
Aliquam in orci id felis mollis porta ac et orci. Donec viverra, eros ac mattis dapibus, quam ante
porta lectus, accumsan pellentesque nibh metus non felis. Vivamus sed eros quis magna scelerisque
ultrices ac eget velit.

Nunc et odio ut velit posuere viverra. Integer eu mi quis velit dapibus tempus at ut purus. Quisque
congue mollis mauris a hendrerit. Nam viverra est at orci interdum a ullamcorper mi dictum. In id
sapien augue. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum turpis purus, convallis ut sagittis quis, semper vel
mauris. Curabitur vitae felis turpis. Fusce augue nibh, consectetur non vestibulum et, bibendum sit
amet lectus. Nulla at imperdiet metus. Donec non est velit, non fringilla ipsum. Fusce elementum neque
a nibh egestas sodales. Mauris ut lorem hendrerit metus interdum malesuada. Nam tempus sodales neque
vitae bibendum. Vestibulum ac est sit amet dolor vehicula semper at sed ante. Nunc at neque urna, in
volutpat orci. Praesent eu velit neque, quis rutrum metus. Nunc eu ipsum sit amet ligula mattis
porttitor sit amet id felis. Integer volutpat aliquam odio et feugiat.
</div>
```

[Chrome view](http://screencast.com/t/cw24dPyVtFHB) and firefox view screencast.com/t/8qE9ZrY57

**UPD: Use column-fill: auto;**

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have restricted your `div`'s height to `500px`.

Remove the that from your style properties.

Make it:

```
 <div style="text-align: justify; border: solid; -webkit-columns: 8; -moz-column-count: 8; font-size: 12px; line-height: 2;">
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rjkb4291/1/).